# Ethernet connection Ubuntu 18.04 not working

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet, connection

I had installed ubuntu 18.04 on my Desktop and network doesn't work, also the icon doesn't appear. I don't have wifi adapter.

this is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
vendor: Interl Corporation
physical id: 1f.6
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
version:00
width:32 bits
clock: 33Mhz
capabilities: pm msi cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

output of `ip link show`

```
1: lo: LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UKNOWN mode DEFAULT grou default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

output of `ip address`

```
1: lo: LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UKNOWN mode DEFAULT grou default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you open a terminal and edit your question posting the output of `ip link show` and `ip address`?

Comment: @MrShunz I've added them

Comment: What is the response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100` Please edit your question to show the result.

Comment: I'd fixed reinstalling the driver compiled without the checksum control. I'd followed this solution https://superuser.com/questions/1104537/how-to-repair-the-checksum-of-the-non-volatile-memory-nvm-of-intel-ethernet-co

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a USB persistent boot drive?

Does that then pick up your NIC? Were you able to download updates during installation? I had someone break their network software completely one time. I forget the exact method, I think I created one off boot problems troubleshooting. Basically, I used "apt-offline" + persistent boot USB to download the NIC drivers + manager(s) that I needed, using the broken machine and then installed them after rebooting into the broken machine.

"mkusb" is handy for this if you have another Linux machine.

Edit:

1. Install "mkusb" (Linux) or [some Windows equivalent](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) (I have had Linux for a long time now, so I always use it to make boot USBs).
2. Select / toggle between persistant / live, pick the ISO and then create the USB boot stick.
3. Boot up your machine using one of the persistent options (why persistent? It automatically gives you a partition to store your downloads and allows you to install things onto the USB drive).
4. [Install "apt-offline"](https://superuser.com/questions/393109/how-can-i-download-ubuntu-packages-in-windows-to-install-them-on-an-offline-ubun#563032) ([manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/apt-offline.8.html)) on the USB (this is only if the drive auto-detects your network interface card (NIC) otherwise, the next steps won't help (however, you can carry apt-offline to the broken machine, detect what it needs, take that request back via USB to working machine, get the files and carry them back, your persistent USB being your network cable)
5. [Download the NIC drivers and managers](https://packages.ubuntu.com)
6. Use `dpkg -i < package name >` in the Download folder when booted into the broken machine to install the packages.

Comment: I have a bootable usb with ubuntu but I don't understand exactly what I have to do, can u please explain better ?

Comment: @AndreaBellizzi - Added it as steps with some links.

Comment: there is a simple solution if I have access to internet?

Comment: @AndreaBellizzi Buy another more compatible network card and try plug it into a PCI slot, perhaps?