# Wired Ethernet not working Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, ethernet

I've got this quite common Problem.
I have just installed **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Desktop** (and selected minimal Installation) on a Toshiba C660-10F Notebook and had it connected to my LAN network all the time. During the install I had some network connection, but after the reboot it stopped working. **The LAN connection works whenever I remove the cable, turn on the computer and then plug it in.** Also after a sleep the connection drops. When I restart the computer without a cable and then plug it in it also does not work. I need to shut it off and turn it on without cable.

I have tried the first answer of this thread, but it did not work, maybe I did something wrong?

[Ethernet connection Ubuntu 18.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079443/ethernet-connection-ubuntu-18-04-not-working)

I changed my /etc/network/interfaces file to

```
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlp6s0
iface wlp6s0 inet dhcp
```

ifconfig prints:

```
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 6849  bytes 586042 (586.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6849  bytes 586042 (586.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::6754:328a:2ca:11be  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:ed:de:74:66:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 81100  bytes 104343532 (104.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 6385
        TX packets 50258  bytes 4861359 (4.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17
```

**lshw -C network**

```
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Passwort für benutzer: 
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       Hersteller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:06:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp6s0
       Version: 01
       Seriennummer: 4c:ed:de:74:66:22
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:17 memory:d1400000-d1403fff
```

**lspci -v | grep -i ethernet -A 10**

```
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -i ethernet -A 10
[sudo] Passwort für benutzer: 
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
```

**cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**if config prints when lan is connected:**

```
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ ifconfig
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::111c:c864:1de2:e3eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 88:ae:1d:fc:15:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5804097  bytes 6757236146 (6.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7843422  bytes 7870222047 (7.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 1299  bytes 127499 (127.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1299  bytes 127499 (127.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::6754:328a:2ca:11be  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:ed:de:74:66:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 286334  bytes 277731993 (277.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 44517
        TX packets 81969  bytes 6275155 (6.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17
```

I have also tried adding enp1s0 to the /etc/network/interfaces file and then rebooted my computer, but that did not help so I reversed all of the changes in that file. Now it only has the first three lines in it

With the Ethernet cable plugged in and connected and the wifi turned off:

```
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Passwort für benutzer: 
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp1s0
       Version: 05
       Seriennummer: 88:ae:1d:fc:15:51
       Größe: 100Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 100Mbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=10.0.0.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:16 ioport:3000(Größe=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       Hersteller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:06:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp6s0
       Version: 01
       Seriennummer: 4c:ed:de:74:66:22
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:17 memory:d1500000-d1503fff
benutzer@C660-10F:~$ lspci -v | grep -i ethernet -A 20
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

Comment: What is the make and model of your network card? I've run into a situation where the correct driver was in a live install for my network card, but it did not get installed properly into my system. You may need to install a driver.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I hope it helps you.

Comment: Is this a server or desktop installation? Edit your question and show me `lspci -v | grep -i ethernet -A 10` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: @heynnema I've added the answers in bold, so that you can easily find them.

Comment: It looks like when the ethernet cable is plugged in, it's working. I have to redo two commands with the cable connected... `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci -v | grep -i ethernet -A 20` (no sudo). Then we'll do a few more commands once I seen that output.

Comment: @heynnema Here you are!

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` file should look like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then, in the `terminal` do:

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms` # install a different ethernet driver

`reboot` # reboot the computer and verify network operation

**Update #1:**

Let's manually load the driver for it...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modules` # edit this file

At the END of the file, add:

```
# load ethernet driver at boot time
r8168
```

Save the file. Quit the editor. Reboot with the ethernet cable attached.

Comment: Sorry that did not work... The driver installed properly, but I still have no connection when I leave the cable plugged in.

Comment: @MatMay see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: No, it is still not working...

Comment: @MatMay lets check your BIOS. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer version BIOS.

Comment: @MatMay status please